# What is the make and model of this biplane?

Tags: aircraft-identification, biplane

This photo is of one of my friend's great grandfather:

[image: Unidentified biplane]

We wish to commemorate a museum in his name as he was a highly regarded person in his area, so we wish to show this photo in the museum with details of the plane.

Comment: A bit more information about the photo may help. Approximately when was is taken? Do you know the location?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

It's a [De Havilland DH.83 Fox Moth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Fox_Moth)

[image: Picture of a DH.83 Fox Moth]

<sup>Source [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Fox_Moth#/media/File:De_Havilland_DH-83_Fox_Moth,_Croydon_Air_Service_AN1041908.jpg). Photographer:  Chris Finney</sup>

With a bit of image contrast and brightness modification, the registration can be read on the underside of the wing: VT-AEA.

VT is the registration prefix for India since the 1930's

The historic registration can be found on [www.airhistory.org.uk](http://www.airhistory.org.uk/gy/reg_VT-.html) and [here](https://www.ab-ix.co.uk/pdfs/vt-aaa.pdf).

> | Registr. | Type | Serial # | Reg. History | Owners | Date | Cert. # | Fate |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | VT-AEA | DH.83 Fox Moth | 4043 |  | The Bombay Flying Club Ltd | 01.05.33 | 173 | Reregistered 6.12.37 |
> | VT-AEA | DH.83 Fox Moth | 4043 | VT-AEA | GB Keshein, Bombay | 6.12.37 | 173/2 | Reregistered 1.2.38 |
> | VT-AEA | DH.83 Fox Moth | 4043 | VT-AEA | Air Services of India Ltd, Bombay | 1.2.38 | 173/3 | Cancelled 10.7.41 |

The aircraft was first owned by the Flying club of Bombay since 1933, then briefly by G.B. Keshein in Bombay and then by Air Services of India until 1941.

Comment: Just had to comment to say what a wonderful answer this is.  You could have stopped at make and model, but you chose not to; there's heaps of detail but it's still concise.  +1.